# How to translate JavaScript string in TurboGears

Tags: javascript, python, internationalization, turbogears

I can translate strings in python and html files. But When I translate JavaScript strings, I get this error in browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

My setup.py:

```
message_extractors={'wiki20': [
        ('**.py', 'python', None),
        ('templates/**.html', 'genshi', None),
        ('public/javascript/index.js', 'javascript', None),
        ('public/**', 'ignore', None)
]},
```

JavaScript file content:

```
$("#bulbunu2").html(_('jquery two add this..! bla2'));
```

When I run `python setup.py extract_messages`, I see js strings in .pot file,(command generate JavaScript strings) but browser give error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

TurboGears by itself does not provide a javascript gettext library, after you gathered and translated the strings like you probably already did you will need javascript library to read .po files and a javascript library to translate your strings.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/po2json to read `.po` files and convert them to `JSON`, then you can use http://slexaxton.github.io/Jed/ or any other translation library for the `_()` function itself.